# What happens if a person is deported to a country that previously refused asylum?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, france, eu, sweden, refugees

What will happen in the following scenario:

- You seek asylum at a European country
- Rejected
- Travel to another country
- Seek asylum
- Based on the concept of first country of asylum, you get caught and sent to the first country.

Is there a legal way to stop them from sending you back?

If they sent you to first country, are they going to send you to your home country?

How is this process in general?

Thanks

Comment: I think a tag for "Asylum" would be a useful addition.

Comment: There isn't one, I searched

Comment: I did too. That's why I made the suggestion.

Comment: They won't send you back to the first country. Deportees are sent to the country where they have unfettered rights of access. Typically that means their home country.

Comment: @user56513 I'm talking here about the application of Dublin Regulations. Consider that the first country accepted the request from second country to take charge or take back the person.

Comment: The country in which the asylum seeker first applies for asylum is responsible for either accepting or rejecting the claim, and the seeker may not restart the process in another jurisdiction.

Comment: If you are rejected by the first country, then you will typically be deported or removed in due course.  If you are not held in a secure facility and manage to travel to another EU country and issue another claim for asylum there, that EU country will transfer you back to the first country, who will hold you in a secure facility before removing you back to a country which will accept you when it is safe for you to go there.  The second EU country wont even consider the asylum request, you are the property of the first country in that respect.

Comment: If you are rejected and travel to a non-EU country and seek asylum there, then it depends on the agreements between those countries - typically, the second asylum request will be considered on its merits, but you won't be deported back to the first country (they wont accept you), you will be held in a secure facility in the second country and deported to a country that is guaranteed to accept you when it is safe for you to go there.

Comment: @David This isn't really a travel question. It really belongs on [expatriates.se] and there is an [asylum](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/asylum) tag there.

Comment: @ReddHerring Hadn't considered that...I agree.

Comment: @Moo Thanks, this is answering my question, is there a way for them not to send you back to your country?

Comment: @David it is related since there is this tag https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/refugees please read the description.

Comment: @bomsn have somewhere else to go that you are guaranteed to be accepted at, eg you have a non-revocable citizenship for that country, and then try and convince the deporting countries immigration to send you there.  The only time they won't deport you to a place you are guaranteed entry to is when that place is demonstrably unsafe for you - and that danger needs to come from something like government action, war or the like.  The country simply being more dangerous (criminal activity, personal threats against you by family members et al) than other countries doesn't count.

Comment: @Moo does that mean you tell them to send you to a war place for example? I don't think this would work since they already have information regarding where you came from.

Comment: @bomsn my comment says exactly the opposite of that...

Answer (score 4):

You will only be deported to a country that the deporters know will accept you.

This will be the country you came from only if they know that you have permission to return there. You may sometimes ask to be deported to a specific country If You can demonstrate you have permission to enter, but in case of any doubt most countries will deport you to your country of citizenship.

If both countries are within the EU then you cannot start a second claim in the second country. They will send you back to the first country (which you cannot prevent) to continue processing. Since you have been rejected this means voluntary departure or deportation as described above. Theoretically you might volunteer to depart from second country rather than return to the first, but since you have already deceived them once you are going to be cut no slack.

Comment: Are you sure about that?  The OP clarified in the comments they were asking about the application of the Dublin Regulation, in which case the asylum seeker *would* be transferred back to the first EU country from any other EU country - its not about permission to return there, its about that EU countries obligation to deal with the applicants asylum claim.

Comment: I think this answer was based only off of one part of my question `deport` I'm not asking specifically about deport which means sending back to home country, I may have used the wrong term but everything else is explained in regard to Dublin Regulations as described in my comments.

Comment: @Moo that is correct.